# reporting configuration in TFS 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, tfs-reports

TF221106: Reporting for Team Foundation Server cannot execute job Full Analysis Database Sync for TEAM FOUNDATION because the Analysis Services processing is offline. Use the Team Foundation Administration Console to start reporting

Comment: Shows when run reports"An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)
Warning: Fatal error 829 occurred at May 30 2016 8:04PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator."

Answer (score 0):

Open Team Foundation Administration Console, select **Reporting**, check whether you have configured the jobs well, and whether these jobs are started.

[image]

Comment: I have checked & seems all are ok.all status is in Idle..... can you share your mail Id then i can send the image..

Comment: "ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "ReportServer" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'."  Showing in Reporting Service Log File in SQL Server.....

Comment: Stop the Jobs, and click Edit to test the connection for warehouse and cube. Also, check this article to make sure the account has appropriate permission: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737953(v=vs.120)

Comment: Shows such kind of Error now"An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)
Database ID 6, Page (1:179) is marked RestorePending, which may indicate disk corruption. To recover from this state, perform a restore."

Comment: It seems your reporting server is not configured well. Follow this article to add a report server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn148128%28v=vs.120%29.aspx